# crontab task execute twice

Tags: linux, cron

this is my crontab configuration：
        `*/15 * * * * /home/chenglei/scripts/recharge_monitor.sh`
but ，every 15mins, it seems like the script executes twice.

in the scrpit I '>>' something to a file.
I use 'echo "$cardmsg" >> $MonitorLog' to print to file.

the result I want is:

```
    08-06 08:57 a recharge [85] in past 15 mins
    08-06 08:58 ca recharge [158] in past 30 mins
```

but the fact is why:

```
        08-06 09:30 a recharge [85] in past 15 mins.
        08-06 09:30 a recharge [68] in past 15 mins.
        08-06 09:31 ca recharge [158] in past 30 mins.
        08-06 09:31 ca recharge [158] in past 30 mins.
```

and you see the second lines is wrong.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Impossible to say w/o seeing your script.  There's nothing to suggest that cron fires twice (unless you can find that in the systems log somewhere).

Comment: in shell script :   echo "$cardmsg" >> $MonitorLog.

Comment: ps -A to check if there are not two crond running

Comment: ps -A  | grep crond
 2989 ?        00:00:01 crond

Comment: I assume you already tried running your script without cron, so it does what you think it does. So maybe you added the cronjob to root and a user. You can check it adding `echo $USER` to your script.

Comment: @kunpengku: yes, I saw that in the original post. But that's **one** line, and useless for any debugging; who/what says that it's not executed twice, e.g. in a loop where a condition you're checking doesn't evaluate to what you expect?

Comment: @Mikel Pascual  I try $USER. unfortunately, the user is the same one.

Comment: @Leo You are right.There 2 crond running. Thank all。

Answer (score 1):

try

```
ps -A
```

to check if there are not two crond running

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that there's no double `crond` running at the same time?

Try this and check...

```
ps -A
```

Answer (score 0):

try using ps aux | grep cron may be there are two instances running

or

try looking into /var/spool/cron/ check if all the entries are right

else try restarting crond